# Error: the property name 'firstname' specified for the type microsoft.crm.sdk.data.services is not valid

Tags: c#, wcf, jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Getting this error when using the CRM 2011 oData service to create a contact.

```
var newContact = Object();
newContact.firstname = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ct_leadconversioncontactfirstname").getValue();
newContact.lastname = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ct_leadconversioncontactlastname").getValue();
newContact.gendercode = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ct_leadconversioncontactgender").getValue();
newContact.jobtitle = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ct_leadconversioncontactjobtitle").getValue();
newContact.websiteurl = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ct_leadconversioncontactwebsite").getValue();

var jsonContact = window.JSON.stringify(newContact);

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: jsonContact,
    url: methodUrl,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //ensures the results will be returned as JSON.
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: successCallback,
    error: failedCallback
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess from the error is your url is wrong.

Make sure the `methodUrl` parameter is something like:

```
url: <your servuer url> /XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet"
```

As it looks like the request is saying "I get what your sending but where your posting it to doesn't have a property of first name on the object"

So check its posting to the `ContactSet`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's definitely posting to the correct place. I've used fiddler to verify where and what it's sending.

Comment: Actually, it looks like oData uses the "Display Name" of a property with the spaces removed. Is this right? I just called ContactSet and looked at the fields and it shows "FirstName". That property has a name of "firstname" and a display name of "First Name".

Comment: Yes thats correct, its not the lower case schema name, if you browse to it you can find the case to use

Answer (score 0):

It takes the Schema Name as mentioned in the field of the associated entity.